# Windows VBscript - XMLHttpRequest Returning Old Content

Tags: windows, vbscript, xmlhttprequest

In my vbscript file, I am using the Microsoft.xmlhttp object to access my .txt file on my web server. I have changed the file's content, but the vbscript keeps showing the old content of the .txt file. I have no idea what could be causing this and I tried it with multiple vbscripts, all with the same problem but no error generated.

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: Send the request to this url:

```
url & "?t=" & Now() & " " & Timer()
```

To avoid caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the data is cached and if your URL doesn't change, you get the old, cached data. Try adding a date / time parameter to your AJAX call:

```
objReq.open("GET", "[your url]?_t=" & Replace(CStr(CDbl(Now())), ".", ""), True)
```

Comment: I thought it would be something like that. But I am sending the request to a txt file, so will the _t paramater have any effect?

Comment: I think I see now,  will the page cache differently because the Date will always be different, causing a different URL?

Comment: Yes, because the URL is different, the browser will not find it in the cache and will send the request to the web server. Alternatively, you could set a request header: 
`objReq.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")`

Comment: I just tried this code, and Date() returns 1/29/13. Is there any way to get a time parameter of milliseconds?

Comment: Yes, use with `Time` or `Now` directly. See my updated answer.

Comment: Update: the Timer() function returns number of seconds since midnight, including milliseconds. I now use Now() & " " & Timer().