# VBScript getting the same file twice when intermittently reading from a webpage

Tags: vbscript, download, sleep

I'm using the following code to download a webpage and save it to file:

```
function download(sFileURL, sLocation, async)
  download = false
  set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
  objXMLHTTP.open "GET", sFileURL, async
  on error resume next
  objXMLHTTP.send()
  if err.number = 0 then
    do until objXMLHTTP.Status = 200
      wscript.echo objXMLHTTP.Status
      wcript.sleep(200)
    loop
    if objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
      set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
      objADOStream.Open
      objADOStream.Type = 1
      objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
      objADOStream.Position = 0    
      set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      If objFSO.Fileexists(sLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile sLocation
      Set objFSO = Nothing
      objADOStream.SaveToFile sLocation
      objADOStream.Close
      objXMLHTTP.Close
      set objADOStream = Nothing
      download = true
    end if
  else
    download = false
  end if
  set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
end function
```

I'm calling it once passing it (url, filename1, false)

and then I sleep for x seconds

and call it again with (url, filename2, false)

I can see the x delay between the properties of the 2 files on disk, but the second file is the exact same as the first file that is downloaded. I know this for certain because I have a server timer.

Is there some sort of strange caching going on, or something wrong with my download function? To be fair I did copy it from the internets...

Comment: First step to troubleshooting things: remove `On Error Resume Next` from your code. Is there a caching proxy between your client and the server?

Comment: it looks like there is, but I don't actually know. I have got around the problem just now by calling a seperate vbscript to do the downloading after the delay. Is there a more elegant solution I could include in just a single script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows VBscript - XMLHttpRequest Returning Old Content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574129/windows-vbscript-xmlhttprequest-returning-old-content)